# Convert an Icon to IPicture in .NET 4.0?

Tags: .net, vb6, .net-4.0, ole, system.drawing

One of the standard and (somewhat) supported answers was to use *Support.IconToIPicture* from the **Microsoft.VisualBasic.Compatibility** assembly.  However, in .NET 4.0, "[This API is now obsolete](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.compatibility.vb6.support.icontoipicture(VS.100).aspx)".

Yes, there are various [solutions](http://blogs.msdn.com/rgregg/archive/2006/11/27/converting-bitmaps-to-ipicturedisp.aspx) out there, but I would think that if Microsoft was obsoleting this method, there would be another "supported" alternative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe, this API is obsolete, because IPicture is an OLE interface. By working with it, you dive into the unmanaged world which Microsoft doesn't want you to. You could reproduce the behavior by calling
`IntPtr aHIcon = Icon.GetHicnFromIcon(yourIcon);`

Then you need to pass this handle to OleCreatePictureIndirect (the code is in C++):

```
PICTDESC aDesc;
aDesc.cbSizeofstruct = sizeof PICTDESC;
aDesc.picType = PICTYPE_ICON;
aDesc.icon.icon = aHIcon;

IPicture * aPict = 0;
OleCreatePictureIndirect(&aDesc, __uuidof(IPicture), TRUE, (void **) &aPict);
```

The only difficulty -- you will need to provide a COM interop code for wrapping the C++ structure and function call.

Comment: @Dan: as you say, you are dealing with **OLD** COM servers, that why you need an obsolete API.

Comment: @Dan: don't get me wrong. My point is: you are dealing with legacy code, do not expect that new languages support legacy code indefinitely. Just use a 3.5 DLL wrapper to the call and move on.

Comment: Correct, Dan; so if you are planning on moving the VB(.net) code that calls Support.IconToIPicture() over to framework 4, then you should replace that call with something similar to this answer - using .Net COM interop. Are you looking for an answer that shows the COM interop being done in VB(.net)? I am not sure what type of answer you are looking for. BTW, the "clue" as to why it is being abandoned is in the message "Microsoft.VisualBasic.Compatibility.* classes are obsolete and supported within 32 bit processes only."

Comment: OK, I think I understand; I would suggest that Thomas Quinn's solution looks perfect, and you mentioned that in your question so you are aware of it. I would suspect they (MS) are obsoleting the VB6 compatibility stuff because there's little (less) need for VB6 conversions anymore and it is costly to maintain the code. In this case, I would not expect a replacement for the obsoleted code.